# How do I show number of fetching of a data in a MySQL data base?

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to show to user how many time a data has been accessed. I am using MySQL and PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short and simple:

```
select * from mytable where ID=$field_id;
update mytable set count_field=count_field+1 where ID=$field_id;
```

I hope you get the point

Answer (score 5):

You would have to implement this yourself as some counter value that you increment whenever you run a query on that data.

Comment: how do I do it?? do you have any sample??

Comment: It will take more than a comment box to explain it, perhaps you should take a look at how you can use a database in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

make a function increaseVisits($userId) where you update the numberVisits of the user and let this function run everytime he logs in to the system.